# How to install grunt globally in VS2015

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I tried the following, but get this exception:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might check, you might need to run a command prompt with elevated permissions in order to install globally.

Just a note, Visual Studio comes with it's own archaic versions of Node and Grunt, so if you go to the Quick Launch Toolbar in the upper right-hand corner of the screen and type "External Web Tools" you can force Visual Studio to use the globally-installed version. Just add a path to the global Grunt installation and move it to the top of the list. Close Visual Studio and re-open and you should be all set.